# Selenium para completar un formulario de una ventana pop-up en JAVA

Tags: java, selenium

Buen día amigos,
Estoy realizando la automatización de un aplicativo, el problema es que el aplicativo parece ser desarrollado mediante Javascript,

tengo el problema que doy clic en el botón "Agregar" y me abre un pop up de un formulario... pero no puedo diligenciar ese formulario no sé porqué,

Lo demás ya lo hice mediante el FindElement(By.xpath("nombre")); Pero cuando ingreso a la ventana pop-up a diligenciar el formulario no me llena los campos,

alguien me ayuda?

gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Para manejar diferentes ventanas o pop-ups puedes utilizar el método `getWindowHandles()` para obtener la lista de ventanas y el método `switchTo().window("idDeTuVentana")` para moverte entre ellas.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo bastante bueno que yo he utilizado varias veces y he obtenido de la respuesta a *[How to handle Pop-up in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19409121)* de [LINGS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392498/lings):

```
String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Almacena tu ventana actual
String subWindowHandler = null;

Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // Obten todas las ventana abiertas
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
}
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // Cámbiate a la ultima ventana (tu pop-up)

// Aquí rellena la información referente a tu pop-up

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);  // Vuelve a tu ventana principal (si lo necesitas)
```

Comment: Se está respondiendo, sin duda. Sin embargo, quizás se podría mejorar un poco. Además del enlace, quizás sería bueno que agregues un breve ejemplo de código en tu respuesta (ya sea copiando el código de la respuesta en SO -dando crédito al auto, o adaptando a como te guste)... No hagamos que tengan que ir a otro lado para leer la respuesta que tendría que estar acá.

Comment: He añadido el ejemplo de código en la respuesta traduciendo los comentarios, no lo puse la primera vez para quitar merito al miembro con la respuesta original.

Comment: al contrario, darle reconocimiento citándolo creo que es positivo